# How do I show my WMS layer using QGIS server and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, qgis-server

I've installed QGIS server and it works fine.
I've put qgs file in the server folder dir and using "Add WMS layer" from QGIS I manage to view the qgs file.

This is how I use GetCapabilities for example:
http://www.localhost.com/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=D:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/MyLondon.qgs&

Now my problem is that in all OpenLayers WMS examples, adding WMS layer looks like this:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
         "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
          {layers: 'basic'}
           );
```

How do I convert my WMS to this format? Where in the URL I set the project name and where the layer name?

Comment: The URL should include the map=value& parameter

Answer (score 4):

I've posted a solution that works for me on http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/. Adjusted to your information, it would be something like:

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
'london_basic', "http://www.localhost.com/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exi",
{
    layers: 'basic', 
    format: 'image/png',
    map: 'D:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/MyLondon.qgs',
}, 
{
    buffer: 1, 
    isBaseLayer: true, 
    graphicZIndex: 0, 
}
);
```

Comment: Thank you , is there a way to configure my qgis server to be more URL friendly like the example I've posted ?

Comment: Anita , in your Vienna example u didn't write use map name , how come ?

Comment: I had only one project in the same folder, so it automatically used that one. Sorry, but what do you mean by URL friendly?

Comment: I meant be able to use url http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0 instead of the entire QGIS settings

Comment: Btw , this still doesnt work for me. I see white rectangle while QGIS does show me the 3 layers inside my project (from the WMS)

Answer (score 1):

The map parameter is part of the service endpoint URL, so the syntax would be like:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
   "http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=D:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/MyLondon.qgs&",
    {layers: 'basic'}
);
```

To convert to a more friendly endpoint URL like `http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?` add a `SetEnvIf` parameter to your Apache config, something like:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe" MS_MAPFILE=D:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/MyLondon.qgs
```

Comment: Interesting. I am experiencing similar problems as the OP. Will try this later.